# How to display only files that have alternate data streams in Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, stream, prompt, alternate

I know that to display alternate data streams of all the files (if any) in command prompt, this is the command `dir /R`. But, how do I do it if I only want to display files that have alternate data streams?

Comment: Put it in a for loop batch.

Comment: what do you mean by put in for loop? because dir /R displays all files, regardless of them having ADS or not. I'm asking if there is a way to only show the files that have ADS, if possible, output them to a text file.

Comment: Can you use "streams" from Microsoft Sysexternals?

Comment: erm i need the command in command prompt, can't use any other programs :/

Comment: "Streams" is a command line tool, for use on the command prompt.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
dir   /s /r | findstr /e ":$DATA"
```

or

```
dir   /r | findstr /e ":$DATA"
```

the first will search in all sub-directories.The second only in current folder. These will show also the ADS assigned to the directory.For only files:

```
dir /a-d  /s /r | findstr /e ":$DATA"
```

Comment: What if the alternate stream is named something other than ":$DATA"?  What about ":HIDDEN" or ":MALWARE", etc.?

Comment: @JimJRHarris - try this: `(echo #>:ads) && (dir /r /s)`  - all alternate data streams end with `$DATA` when dir command is used.