# Created application transferred to the computer at work throw exception is dangerous. Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I create application on my computer, after I sent it to myself on a computer.
I was open Visual Studio with ask my ~"Do you want to open this application?".
I updated this application. And I compiled it. But application run by Debug .exe is blocked by F-Secure.

Is it possible to set in project it is secure app for this computer?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you send it over the net - when downloading something windows adds an alterante data stream to "mark" the downloaded file to be from a unsecure source.

You can remove this alternate data stream marker to solve your problem.

See

- [Wikipedia: ADS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_(ADS))
- [How to display only files that have alternate data streams in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333782/how-to-display-only-files-that-have-alternate-data-streams-in-command-prompt)
- https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Windows_::DATA_alternate_data_stream

Windows stores the download location as ads in the *zone.indentifier* stream. You can inspect your file using windwos power shell:

```
>> Get-Content -Path yourfile.here -Stream zone.identifier
1
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
ReferrerUrl=source url here 
HostUrl=lots of data here
```

and remove the alternate data stream:

```
Remove-item -Path yourfile.here -Stream zone.identifier
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I just create new project and copy all class. And it work.

Comment: @mat Copying will only cope the main stream, so yes, that works as well.